# WSS4J with Spring WS (loading cert from byte array)

Tags: security, encryption, ssl-certificate, spring-ws, wss4j

I am working with Spring integration + Spring WS Security through WSS4JSecurityInterceptor.

I have a WS client consuming a Web service on the server with the next security scenario:
**

1. The server side gives me a .cert file data in byte array after encoding to sign but I don’t know how to give byte array to factory.setKeyStoreLoaction(), here it is expecting the file path, but I have byte array.

Below is the configuration to load jks file from classpath

```
`@Bean
public Crypto myCrypto() throws Exception{
    CryptoFactoryBean factory = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    factory.setTrustStorePassword( "myPass" );
    factory.setKeyStorePassword( "myPass" );
    **factory.setKeyStoreLocation( new ClassPathResource("myNewKeyStore.jks") );**
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}`
```

```
`@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor() throws Exception{

  Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
  interceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken");
  interceptor.setSecurementUsername("user http");
  interceptor.setSecurementPassword("pass http");
  interceptor.setValidationActions("Signature");
  interceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto( myCrypto() );
  interceptor.afterPropertiesSet();
  return interceptor;
}`
```

I need to set key store from byteArray